# Swift collectionview slides on slide alignment

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, padding

I want a visual beauty with collectionview, but I have encountered alignment problems.
I share them with you.
There is no problem when the page is first loaded.

[image: one image]

When I scroll to the collectionview, there are some shifts.

[image: two image]

What I want is that the collectionview shifts sideways and the alignment of alignments has not changed, but I have tried very hard to find a solution. I share my code with you.

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.celloectionCat.delegate = self
    self.celloectionCat.dataSource = self
    self.celloectionCat?.register(UINib(nibName: "mycell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "mycell")
    self.celloectionCat.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.celloectionCat.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    self.celloectionCat.isPagingEnabled = true;
    self.celloectionCat.alwaysBounceVertical = false

}


extension Cell : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let padding: CGFloat =  45.0
    let hpadding: CGFloat = 15.0
    let collectionViewWidthSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
    let collectionViewHeightSize = collectionView.frame.size.height - hpadding

    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidthSize / 2   , height: collectionViewHeightSize / 2  )
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when paging is enabled, the collection view will stop the content view at multiples of the collection view size.

One approach to your problem would be to split the cells into sections, specifically, one section per page, and four cells (at most) per section. If you set up the section insets correctly, then one section will be the size of the collection view, and the cells will be aligned in the center of the section.

Here is your code with slight changes. I used hardcoded numbers, but I advise against this in your code (also, you should consider moving the cell size calculations out of the sizeForItem method, since this will be called multiple times, yet the size doesn't change).

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
    didSet {
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell identifier", for: indexPath)
    // setup your cell

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let padding: CGFloat =  45.0
    let hpadding: CGFloat = 15.0
    let collectionViewWidthSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
    let collectionViewHeightSize = collectionView.frame.size.height - hpadding

    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidthSize / 2   , height: collectionViewHeightSize / 2  )
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 15
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 15
}
```